# How to enable _USE_UNIX98 (Gcc/C++ v2.96)

Tags: c++, gcc

I've a C++ application that works in actual compilers (I compile it with eclipse). 
Now, I need compile it on a very old compiler version (gcc/c++ v2.96) on a Redhat 7.3 with Kdevelop.

When I compile the app it gives the following error: swprintf undeclared. 
wchar.h header it's included, but I saw this file in the RH7.3 OS and only declare this function if __USE_UNIX98  __USE_ISOC99 are declared.

How can I enable __USE_UNIX98?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU libc defines the features that should be enabled in all of its headers using a special system header `<features.h>`. If you define the appropriate macros, `<features.h>` will define `__USE_UNIX98` for you.

The typical way to get all functions, regardless of what standard (if any) covers them, is by adding `-D_GNU_SOURCE` on the command-line. Getting only the functions covered by a specific standard requires defining the macro as specified in that standard using the value specified in that standard, such as `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L`. The precise values that are supported on your particular implementation are probably easiest found by inspecting `/usr/include/features.h` manually.

Answer (score 2):

From inspection of `<features.h>` defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to 500 or greater will cause `__USE_UNIX98` to be defined